# ManyToMany query in JPA

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables/entities. All working fine (getters and setters omitted).

```
@Entity
    public class Book() {
    @Id;
    int id;
    @ManyToMany
    List<Category> categories;
}

@Entity
public class Category {
    @Id
    int id;
    @ManyToMany
    List<Book> books;
}
```

JPA/Hibernate creates database structure as expected with a join table called book_category that contains the fields book_id and category_id.

Categories are created in advance so not all of them have books.
I want to query for distinct categories that has books in them.

The following SQL-query does it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <things> FROM book_category JOIN category ON category.id = book_category.category_id
```

But how can i get the list of categories from the Repository?

Answer (score 2):

If you want all categories which have books assigned to them, then I think you just need a query on the `Category` entity which checks the size of its book collection:

```
select c from Category where size(c.books) > 0
```

Even if querying the junction table directly would be possible, e.g. via a native query, I don't think that this would be considered good JPA practice.  Rather, the two many-to-many entities you already have should allow you to perform the queries you need.

Comment: So i tried this in the category Repository
`List<Category> findDistinctByBookIsGreaterThan(int i)` but it gives me a `NoSuchElementException`

Comment: Is a direct JPQL query not an option?

Comment: @jared I don't know the exact named method syntax for my answer.  But you should always be able to use JPQL directly if needed.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want a JPA Repository for your Categories. This will create a repository and then you can use it to get the categories which have books in them. You will just need to get the Book Id. JPA is very flexible, so this may not be what you want exactly, but try it out yourself.

```
public interface CategoryRepository extends JpaRepository <Category, Integer>
{
    List<Category> findByBookId(Integer book);
}
```

EDIT: Alright, it's been a long day and im tired af. How about if you try the reverse?

```
public interface BookRepository extends JpaRepository <Book, Integer>
{
    List<Book> findAllByCategoryId(Integer category);
}
```

then check if it's null or not.

Comment: But i want all categories that has books in them, regardless of what book it is.

Comment: This code will find all categories that have a book in them and show them. It will not find a book if there's no books.  

"List<Category> categroyList= categoryRepository.findByBookId(bookId)"  


Then you just make a check to see if categoryList is empty then it should not show it in the model. If you can, post your controller so I can see what you're doing exactly. I mean, that's what you're looking for, right? If the category is empty it should not show? If there are books in it, it should show

Comment: See my edit, I'm just gonna quit until tomorrow when I can think straight again.